# Many apps like Tweetbot, Facebook, etc., allow you to close an image overlay by pulling down/up on it. How is this achieved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

In the new Tweetbot app, images can be "thrown" in various directions to close them. In Facebook's app, you can pull it down or up to close it.

I was curious how such an effect is achieved. I'm using `UIScrollView` to implement the zoom and pan functionality, but how does one pull and release the image and have a method fire?

It's not done with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is it, as that would conflict with the `UIScrollView` pan gesture recognizer? It very well may be though, as you're only able to dismiss the images when fully zoomed out (and the scrollview can't be panned) so there wouldn't be any conflicts.

I'm sorry for the lack of code (as I'm confused as how to even start) but I hope the above examples do well in explaining the functionality I'm describing.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `-scrollViewDidScroll:` in your `UIScrollView`'s `delegate`.

Or subclass `UIScrollView` and override `-setContentOffset:`.